# How can I get the sum of value inside the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How to add the value inside array that I've for each by the way here is my code I want to add the values inside `total_halin`

```
function generateReport($d1,$d2){
    $arr = array();
    $sql="SELECT dm.damage_qty,p.price,p.product_name,SUM(ps.pcs_bought) AS TOTAL_PCS FROM products p 
INNER JOIN sold_products ps
ON p.id = ps.product_id
LEFT JOIN damages dm
ON p.id = dm.product_id
WHERE ps.date_ordered BETWEEN '".$d1."' AND '".$d2."'
GROUP BY p.id";
    $result = Database::$conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows>0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $i = new Product();
                $i->prodname = $row['product_name'];
                $i->total_pieces = $row['TOTAL_PCS'];
                $i->total_halin = $row['price'] * $row['TOTAL_PCS'];

                $i->damage = $row['damage_qty'];
                $arr[] = $i;
            }

        }
        return $arr;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't YELL.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_sum() returns the sum of values in an array.

Example

```
<?php
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($a) . "\n";

$b = array("a" => 1.2, "b" => 2.3, "c" => 3.4);
echo "sum(b) = " . array_sum($b) . "\n";
?>
```

Result would be like 
sum(a) = 20
sum(b) = 6.9

Hope that answers your question

Comment: it says Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array

Comment: Are you passing $i->total_halin; try getting it like $sum_arr = $i->total_halin; then pass $sum_arr to array_sum as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tot=0;
foeach($i->total_halin as $key=>$value)
{
    $tot+=$value;
}
```

$tot is the sum